# When one can write $M=\mathbb{Z} \cdot m$ for some $m \in M$?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a *finitely generated* $\mathbb{Z}$-module such that $p^n \cdot m=0$ for all $m \in M$.

Assume also that $M$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$-module.

**Question:**

When can we write $M=\mathbb{Z} \cdot m$ for some $m \in M$ ?

or in other word, when is $M$ a cyclic $\mathbb{Z}$-module ?

---

My effort:

If the rank of $M$ as a free $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$-module be $1$, then we have
$$M \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}.$$
In the above case $M$ being torsion-free $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, so we conclude $M$ is a cyclic $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$-module and hence $$M=\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} \cdot m, ~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$
for some $m \in M$.

But I want show $M=\mathbb{Z} \cdot m$ for some $m \in M$.

As the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $M$ factors through the quotient $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, we have $$p^n\cdot m=0 \Rightarrow z \cdot m=(z+p^n \mathbb{Z}) \cdot m,$$
which says we can view the elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ as belonging to $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$.

From relation $(1)$, we have $$M=\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} \cdot m \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} \cdot m \oplus p^n \mathbb{Z} \cdot m \cong \mathbb{Z} \cdot m$$
for some $m \in M$.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: "$M= \mathbb Z \cdot m$ for some $m \in M$" means *exactly* that $M$ is cyclic and $m$ is a generator of $M$. Being cyclic implies that $$M \cong \Bbb Z / p^k \Bbb Z$$ for some $k \le n$.

Comment: @Crostul, thanks for your help. So you mean if $M \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^k \mathbb{Z}$, then we can express $M=\mathbb{Z} \cdot m$ for some $m \in M$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *a lot* of misconceptions in this question. I will only address those that are relevant for answering the question (and formulating it properly).

> Let $M$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-module such that $p^n \cdot m=0$ for all $m \in M$.

Equivalently $M$ is an abelian group, in which the order of every element divides $p^n$. In particular $M$ is a $p$-group.

> Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, by structure theorem $M=F\oplus T$, where $F$ is free $\mathbb{Z}$-module and $T$ is torsion $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

This is not true. The structure theorem holds for *finitely generated* modules over a PID.

> Therefore $M$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$-module.

This simply does not follow, even if $M$ were finitely generated. I have no idea what your line of thought could be. For a very simple counterexample, take $p=2$ and $M=\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ and $n=2$. Be sure to look up the definition of a *free* module.

> **Question:**
>
> When can we write $M=\mathbb{Z} \cdot m$ for some $m \in M$ ?

You already note that the action of $\Bbb{Z}$ on $M$ factors over $\Bbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z}$, and so
$$\mathbb{Z} \cdot m=(\Bbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z})\cdot m.$$
By definition $M=(\Bbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z})\cdot m$ for some $m\in M$ if and only if $M$ is a cyclic $\Bbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z}$-module. Be sure to look up the definition of a *cyclic* module.

Comment: Thanks for your nice comment-cum-answer. It was very helpful. So the question reduces to showing $M$ is cyclic as $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$-module ? Am I right ?

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that $M$ is finitely generated

Comment: Would you help me a little bit more to clear my understanding ?  By definition of cyclic module, if $M$ is cyclic $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$-module generated by some $m$, then $M \cong  (\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z})/\left\langle m \right\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/mp^n \mathbb{Z}$. Does the opposite hold ?

Comment: Suppose $M$ is free $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$-module of finite rank and $M$ is finitely generated in my question. When will $M$ be cyclic as $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$-module ? If we change $\mathbb{Z}$ by the discrete valuation ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$, would it help ? Please help

Comment: If $M$ is free and of finite rank, then it is finitely generated. It is cyclic if it is generated by one element. Seriously, this is just a matter of looking up the definitions. Please just look them up before asking questions like this here.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen the definitions. I understand your words. But I could decide what I am wanting to show in a proof.  I am refreshing it again to make thing clear in the below comment.

Comment: Suppose it is given $M$ is finitely generated as $\mathbb{Z}$-module such that $p^k \cdot m=0$ for $k \in [1,n]$ and for all $m \in M$. It is also given that $M$ is free $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$-module of finite rank. Is it enough to say $M=\mathbb{Z} \cdot m$ for some $m \in M$ ? Just a final comment please

Comment: Look up the definition of a *free* module, and its *rank*. It is then immediately clear that your question makes no sense at all. I won't engage any further if you refuse to even look up the terms that you are using. I wish you good luck with whatever it may be that you are trying to figure out.

Comment: sorry. Over a principal ideal domain, finitely-generated modules are torsion-free if and only if they are free.

Comment: I think my question makes sense now. The equation $(1)$ holds also. What would you say  ? Second, I want to transfer our comments to chat room. How can I do that ?